# Is there any way to upload a very large file use django on nginx?

Tags: python, django, apache, nginx, webserver

I use django to run my website and nginx for front webserver ,

but when i upload a very large file to my site,

it take me very long time ,

there is some thing wrong when nginx hand upload large file;

the nginx will  send the file to django after receive all my post file;

so this will take me more time;

i want to find some other webserver to replace the nginx;

wish your suggest?

Comment: Uploading large files takes a long time. It just does.

Get used to it.

Comment: if i can stand, i will not post this request.^_^...

Comment: @timger: A different web server isn't going to make the file upload faster.

Answer (score 1):

You problem not in nginx you problem in nginx settings.

If you want handle files with django - you should change some params

[Timeout when uploading a large file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348935/timeout-when-uploading-a-large-file)

Else nginx may handle files itself

http://www.grid.net.ru/nginx/upload.en.html

Answer (score 0):

Nginx is probably the best http server, there is no need to replace it. I will advise you to upload very large files via ftp or nfs share.

Comment: i want to built a website share file use http like amazon s3,so i need a web server can handle upload large file

Comment: @timger
Nginx handles large files very well. Your problem is **django**.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to not pass file to your django application, then you should use:
[`fastcgi_pass_request_body off;`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFastcgiModule#fastcgi_pass_request_body)

Also you may want to use the upload module: http://www.grid.net.ru/nginx/upload.en.html

Answer (score -1):

Look at tornado at http://www.tornadoweb.org/ You may use it beside the django and handle file upload.

On my project I successfully use django with tornado, that handles API calls and long ajax requests.